# A word that describes telling someone you are not going to tell them something but inadvertently telling them

Tags: expressions

For example:

Me: So what do you do for a living?

Guy: I'm a fish and game warden.

Me: Interesting. Well I guess I better not tell you about all the salmon I caught yesterday.

I was thinking sarcasm but I'm fishing for another word.

Comment: You were thinking sarcasm, but in the title you say inadvertently? Makes it difficult to be sure what you're after.

Comment: You've pulled a *Hagrid*.

Comment: What a great point about "pulled a Hagrid"..

Comment: This is an example of speech that Donald Trump uses. It has a name, I knew it once and I'm searching it out again. example: "I'm not going to tell you how much of a liar Lying Ted Cruz is" Hagrid would be a good word, but it's not the official one.

Comment: *Let the cat out of the bag*, unless you are an animal control agent.

Answer (score 3):

If you're *inadvertently* telling them, I think the word is a [blunder](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blunder):

> a foolish tactless remark

or a [gaffe](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gaffe):

> a social blunder, esp a tactless remark

or simple a [slip of the tongue](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slip+of+the+tongue) (often also referred to as a *slip-up*):

> an unintentional utterance; a mistake in speaking.

Answer (score 1):

The rhetorical device goes by several names. *Paralipsis* is one of them.

> **paralipsis** *noun*
> Rhetoric [mass noun] The device of giving emphasis by professing to say little or nothing of a subject, as in not to mention their unpaid debts of several millions.
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paralipsis)

Here are a few more:

> Apophasis is a rhetorical device wherein the speaker or writer brings up a subject by either denying it, or denying that it should be brought up. Accordingly, it can be seen as a rhetorical relative of irony.
>
> The device is also called paralipsis (παράλειψις) – also spelled paraleipsis or paralepsis – or occupatio, and known also as praeteritio, preterition, antiphrasis (ἀντίφρασις), or parasiopesis (παρασιώπησις).
>
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis)

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally reveal a bit of your strategy or intentions, it is called *tipping your hand* (as in, accidentally showing your cards during a game.)